# Using std::bind in std::bind : compilation error (implicit cast)

Tags: c++, c++11, std, stdbind

When I want to create an std::function for wrapping work(..) member, I had a compilation error that tired me.

sample code :

```
class C{ 
public:
    C(){
        std::function<void(void) > f = std::bind(&C::work,
                                                 this,
                                                 std::bind(&C::step1, this),
                                                 std::bind(&C::step2, this));
        QList<decltype(f)> lst;
        lst.append(f);
        .....
    }
private:
    void work(std::function<bool()> fn1, std::function<bool()> fn2 ) {
        if (fn1()) {
            QTimer::singleShot(1, fn2);
        }
        else {
            QTimer::singleShot(5, fn1);
        }
    }

    bool step1(){return true;}
    bool step2(){return true;}
};
```

Compile Error:

```
main.cpp:49: erreur : conversion from 'std::_Bind_helper<false, void (C::*)(std::function<bool()>, std::function<bool()>), C* const, std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<bool (C::*)()>(C*)>, std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<bool (C::*)()>(C*)> >::type {aka std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (C::*)(std::function<bool()>, std::function<bool()>)>(C*, std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<bool (C::*)()>(C*)>, std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<bool (C::*)()>(C*)>)>}' to non-scalar type 'std::function<void()>' requested
                                              std::bind(&C::step2, this));
                                                                        ^
```

Comment: Bind of bind is magic. It doesn't work as you might expect.

Comment: Use lambdas instead of bind.

Comment: Your compilers error statement is telling you the problem, `bind` doesn't do implicit conversion, and the result of `bind(&C::step, this)` is a `_Bind_helper` *not* a `function<bool()>`. You need to do the conversion yourself: `bind(&C::work, this,function<bool()>(bind(&C::step1, this)), function<bool()>(bind(&C::step2, this)))` [Live Example](http://ideone.com/lvVL5z)

Comment: @JonathanMee That works but not for the reason you think it does. `std::bind(&C::step1, this)` itself *is* convertible to `std::function<bool()>` after all.

Comment: when we test with function<bool()>a=std::bind(&C::step1, this),                                                             function<bool()>b=std::bind(&C::step2, this) and bind(&C::work, this, a, b) we get the same problem so I think it's not a problem of implicit conversion

Comment: @Barry Of course it is convertible. I was saying the reason that the OP's code didn't work is because `bind` does not *do* the conversion. For `bind` to work the programmer must do the conversions explicitly. Or do you disagree with that statement?

Comment: @requinham It's absolutely the problem. And the test code you wrote runs fine: http://ideone.com/tzifGe There may be a compiler issue or there's something else going on that you haven't shown me.

Comment: @JonathanMee Yes, that's false. See my answer. Or the linked dupe.

Comment: @Barry And you are right, I'm wrong, per the norm +1. Thanks for setting me straight. So the reason mine works is because I've converted it so it's no longer a `bind`-subexpression. It has nothing to do with implicit conversion.

Comment: @JonathanMee Exactly right.

Comment: @JonathanMee you are right.

Comment: At least I can be right about the end result, even if it takes @Barry to correct my cause ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `bind()` will eagerly evaluate nested `bind` expressions. So instead of ending up with some callable that returns `bool` (as you had intended from `std::bind(&C::step1, this)`), you just end up with `bool`.

Instead, use lambdas:

```
std::function<void(void) > f = [this]{
    work([this]{ return step1(); },
         [this]{ return step2(); });
};
```

Comment: I was wondering if you knew where this issue is referenced. +1

Comment: @MohamadElghawi What do you mean?

Comment: You said: "bind() will eagerly evaluate nested bind expressions". Was just wondering where you read that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Mohamad [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind), see behavior under `operator()`

Comment: @MohamadElghawi "(e.g., another bind subexpression was used as an argument in the initial call to bind), then that bind subexpression is invoked immediately as an lvalue object with the same cv-qualifications as that of g, and its result is passed to the invocable object." http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind#Member_function_operator.28.29